# Java 8 List of Objects to Map<String, List> of values

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to convert `List<Object>` to `Map<String, List>` using `Streams`,

```
public class User{
   String name;
   String age;
   String org;
}
```

I have `List<Users>`, and need to collect into `Map<String, Object> m`,

```
 m.put("names", List of names,);
 m.put("age", List of age);
 m.put("org", List of org);
```

to be use in named query -> eg: `select * from table ... where names in (:names) and age in (:age) and org in (:org)`

as of now I am doing like

```
List<String> names = userList.stream().map(User::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> age= userList.stream().map(User::getAge).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> org= userList.stream().map(User::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to collect all the values while streaming to the list only once ?

Comment: just you a loop

Comment: Why specific Stream ?

Comment: @YCF_L He says juste next : I have `List<User>` so not use to understand all

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
Map<String,List<String>> map =
    userList.stream()
            .flatMap(user -> {
                Map<String,String> um = new HashMap<>();
                um.put("names",user.getName());
                um.put("age",user.getAge());
                um.put("org",user.getOrg());
                return um.entrySet().stream();
            }) // produces a Stream<Map.Entry<String,String>>
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                           Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                              Collectors.toList())));
```

It converts each `User` to a `Map<String,String>` (containing the 3 required properties indexed by the required keys), and then groups the entries of all the user maps by their keys.

EDIT:

Here's another alternative that creates the `Map.Entry`s directly instead of creating the small `HashMap`s, so it should be more efficient:

```
Map<String,List<String>> map =
    userList.stream()
            .flatMap (user -> Stream.of (new SimpleEntry<>("names",user.getName()),
                                         new SimpleEntry<>("age",user.getAge()),
                                         new SimpleEntry<>("org",user.getOrg())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                           Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                              Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Miss one `)` before collect

Comment: @RinsenS Please note I added a more efficient (and more elegant) solution.

Comment: @Eran, thanks a lot for it too !! but can i know whether how to acheive result map of type Map<Object, Object> instead of Map<String, List<String>>, where first Object is key (names) and second Object values is List<names>

Comment: @RinsenS Why would you want to do that? It's better to use the actual types than to use `Map<Object, Object>`.

Comment: @RinsenS If you insist, you can write `Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<>(userList.stream()....)`;

Comment: Yes you are correct, but we already have another lib to which I would need to pass as Map<object, object> ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171079/discussion-between-rinsen-s-and-eran).

Comment: @RinsenS didn't my last comment answer your request?

Comment: @Eran, yes thanks a lot !!!! for it, is it possible for yout to help on this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349126/java8-compare-2-list-of-objects-and-form-a-list-of-map-with-old-and-new-values

Answer (score 6):

[Eran's showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50348352/1898563) how you can accomplish this with streams. As you can hopefully see, it's incredibly ugly.

If your issue with your procedural version is the amount of code duplication, there are other ways besides streams that we can use to solve that problem.

I would refactor the collection to its own method:

```
private static List<String> getProperty(List<User> users, Function<User, String> getter) {
    return users.stream().map(getter).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("names", getProperty(userList, User::getName));
map.put("age",   getProperty(userList, User::getAge));
map.put("org",   getProperty(userList, User::getOrg));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but here we are streaming the userList 3 times right ??

Comment: @RinsenS Yes, we are. Be mindful to not optimise prematurely. Unless you have tens or hundreds of millions of users, it's not likely to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Yes its nice and clean too and thanks a lot for it !!

Comment: Even with millions of users, I wouldn’t be surprised if this solution, streaming three times is more efficient than the alternative. Streaming over a list is not an expensive operation per se. At least not as expensive as performing three million hash operations, compared to the three hash operations of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Generic Solution

Both @Eran and @Michael gives a nice solution, I would like to solve your problem with a generic way :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<User> listUsers = ...
    //Create a List which hold name of field and its value
    List<Map<String, Object>> listMapping = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : listUsers) {
        listMapping.add(fieldNameValue(user));
    }

    //Here group by the name of the field
    Map<String, List<Object>> result = listMapping.stream()
            .flatMap(a -> a.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

}

//This method return a Map which hold names of attributes and its values.
static Map<String, Object> fieldNameValue(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, Object> mapping = new HashMap<>();
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        mapping.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj));
    }
    return mapping;
}
```

In this solution you don't care about the number of fields of the type.

Comment: I thought about a reflection solution, but the getter is called "name" and the map key is "names"

Comment: @Michael I think it is just a mistake from the op it still helpful for others i thought :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. 
Color bean used to separating map value and key from the list.

```
    List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

    colors.add(new Color("RED", "#FF0000"));
    colors.add(new Color("BLUE", "#0000FF"));
    colors.add(new Color("GREEN", "#008000"));

    // construct key-value pairs from name and code fields of Color
    Map<String, String> map = colors.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Color::getName, 
                                                        Color::getCode));
```